# How to get list of Domino Servers on network using .NET?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I want to get list of Domino Servers on the network, and accordingly login into particular server.

I am using C# / Interop.Domino.dll

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Name and Address Book (NAB - usually, the names.nsf database) on a server whose name is known - that NAB has a view with an alias of "Servers", which lists all servers that this server is aware of. (It may not be a complete list of all accessible servers).  If you don't know of any server names to start, you can find the current session user's home mail server, and use that.

So, you want to do something like:

1. Get home mail server - using **eval("@MailDbName");**
2. open names.nsf on that server - **notesSession.getDatabase (server, "names.nsf")**
3. open the Servers view - **db.OpenView ("Servers")**
4. get collection of all server names from that view - **col = vw.allEntries**
5. iterate over all and get server names - **notesViewEntry.ColumnValues(3)**